# my menu button is not workig correct its need to refresh page to work again

Tags: javascript

After opening and closing the menu once, it needs to refresh the page to work. How can I fix it so that it works without needing to refresh?

**js code**

```
const menuBtn = document.querySelector("#menuBtn");
const menu = document.querySelector("#menu");
const sideNav = document.querySelector("#sideNav");
 sideNav.style.right = "-150px"
       menu.onclick = function(open){
    if(sideNav.style.right = "-150px"){
        sideNav.style.right = "0";
        menu.src="/images/211652_close_icon.png"
    }
    menu.onclick =function(close){
    
        sideNav.style.right = "-150px";
        menu.src="/images/588a6507d06f6719692a2d15.png"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

there's a typo here:

```
if(sideNav.style.right = "-150px")
```

it should be ==, = is for assigning values, not comparing

the reason it's not working is this part is overwriting the menu.onclick event handler inside the initial if statement, which prevents the second onclick event from being registered.

```
 menu.onclick =function(close){

    sideNav.style.right = "-150px";
    menu.src="/images/588a6507d06f6719692a2d15.png"
}
```

use a if-else statement instead.

```
if(sideNav.style.right == "-150px"){
    sideNav.style.right = "0";
    menu.src="/images/211652_close_icon.png"
}else{
    sideNav.style.right = "-150px";
    menu.src="/images/588a6507d06f6719692a2d15.png"
}
```

it works on codepen with this